# Excel: Pivot Table Filtering Using VBA/Slicer?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, vlookup, slicers

**Gold star for whoever solves this! :)**

I have a pivot table that has data from various attributes attached to unique ID numbers from an OLAP cube report. When I select ID# as a pivot field and all the corresponding attributes ie: Name,age,etc I end up getting about 10k ID's with 10k corresponding attribute values. I have a list of 3k ID#'s which I want to filter my report by. What is the best way to do this?

**Simple example:** Pivot table displays ID# 1,2,3,4,5 and corresponding attributes such as name,age,etc

I want to filter ID#'s from a column of values I have in another worksheet for example the column in other worksheet would have ID#'s 1,2,3 (Which in theory would omit values 4 and 5 from pivot)

**(Keep in mind I am dealing with thousands of rows this example is made simple just for explanation)**

I thought a VBA slicer combo might work, but I have no clue how to set up a slicer so when it is created it has only values selected from a column of values.

In my example VBA slicer will have ID#'s 1,2,3 selected upon creation or an easy way to select multiple ID#s from a list or something as I can't feasibly click through 3k values

**Possible Solutions I Brainstormed**

I was also thinking maybe just a VLOOKUP or something that will pull ID#'s against the column and also bring all corresponding attributes? The thing is I like the cube report being dynamic and updating with the slicer.

I then also thought to create a slicer based off of another pivot table which is composed simply of a header of ID#'s and lists ID# 1,2,3 I created in another worksheet and try and use that simple slicer against the OLAP cube, but the issue is the slicers have different connections and they can't overlap. :(

**Any and all help is much appreciated!!! :)**

Comment: aren't you over-engineering it. Put your IDs in page filter, loop through and select the filters.

Comment: A nuclear solution to this is to use [ADO MD and send MDX](https://msolap.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/returning-mdx-query-results-in-an-excel-matrix-formula/) queries with `Where` filters right into the OLAP cube. In Excel, when you filter on PivotTable it actually sends new MDX queries to the cube. So you'd either do that or send MDX queries directly.

Comment: @cyboashu It's an OLAP cube and it doesn't seem like OLAP cubes support report filter pages

Comment: @loganreed I don't have access to the back end of the OLAP cube so don't think this will work for me :/

Comment: hmm and how about this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30919753/3961708

Comment: You did not mention what version of Excel you are using, but have you thought about using Power Query (or the integrated functionality in 2016) to get the filtered list. With Power Query you can easily build a query that is the equivalent of an inner join.