# Filtering OLAP fields in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, olap

I update several OLAP fields regularly and was thinking of automating this task.

I tried recording some macros to understand the behind-the-scenes working of OLAP pivot tables and got this.

The following code is generated when I select all the months from October-2016 to October-2017 (the hierarchy in Fiscal Period is Year, Quarter and then Month):

```
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").CubeFields(5). _
        TreeviewControl.Drilled = Array(Array(""), Array( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2017]"))
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Year]").HiddenItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2004]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2005]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2006]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2007]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2008]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2009]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2010]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2011]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2012]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2013]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2014]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2015]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2019]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2016]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Quarter]").HiddenItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2017].[1]")
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Year]").DrilledDown = True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotSelect _
        "'[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2017].[2]'", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Quarter]").DrilledDown = True
    Range("E9").Select
```

I have been searching the internet for any clues on this task and only see `VisibleItemsList` used. When I implement the `VisibleItemsList` code that I see on the internet on my own work, I get errors.

For example the following:

```
Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).PivotFields("[Fiscal Period].[Year].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2015]", "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2016]")
```

gives the error:

`"Unable to get the PivotFields property of PivotTable class"`

I am trying to select only the fiscal years 2015 and 2016 using the above code.

I would be extremely grateful if someone will walk me through this task. This has started proving to be one of the most excruciating I have ever faced. I just need a few pointers on the `VisibleItemsList` property. I am using Excel 2007 if thats relevant.

Here is an image of the pivottable layout:

[image: pivottable layout]

**Additional Information:**

The code when i record the macro selecting only 2015 and 2016 (and not expanding them. The code when i expand the Years and Quarters can be seen above, in which I select all the months from Oct-2016 to Oct-2017) is:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").CubeFields(5). _
        TreeviewControl.Drilled = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Year]").HiddenItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2004]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2005]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2006]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2007]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2008]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2009]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2010]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2011]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2012]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2013]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2014]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2019]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2017]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2018]")
```

Comment: even this doesnt work:
Worksheets(1).PivotTables(1).PivotFields("[Fiscal Period].[Year].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[Fiscal Period].[Year].[2015]", "[Fiscal Period].[Year].[2016]")

Comment: Edit additional information into the question

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2015]", _
        "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2016]")

Comment: @QHarr sure i can do that. can you tell me what exactly do you need to know in addition to what i have already described.

Comment: The _ is a line break. Mean there is a single space before it and the text after it is on a new line. On one line it would look like      
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0").PivotFields( "[Fiscal Period].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2015]", "[Fiscal Period].[All Fiscal Period].[2016]")

Comment: yeah i know about the line break. i just tried your code and it gave, "Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: I meant edit your first comment about what else you have tried into the section of your question where you describe what you have tried and the errors you get. Giving the actual error message is also useful.

Comment: Can you show an image of the pivottable in question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159205/discussion-between-ijhaqqani-and-qharr).

Answer (score 0):

The code the Macro recorder gave to select the Pivotfield was:

```
PivotFields("[Fiscal Period].[Year]")
```

...but you are using:

```
PivotFields("[Fiscal Period].[Year].[Year]")
```

...so perhaps this explains the error.

Comment: i have tried both... "[Fiscal Period].[Year]" gives Application-defined or Object-defined error. 
The only reason I was trying to write [Year] two times was because I had noticed this syntax on different online posts on the internet. Like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919139/vba-to-change-pivot-filter-in-olap-cube-to-a-range

Comment: Okay. Can you fire up the macro recorder, and select only the fiscal years 2015 and 2016, and post the resulting code in your original question?

Comment: I'll do that. But please note that the recorder is only using HiddenItemsList whereas imo the work is better done using VisibleItemsList and thats what my question mainly relates to. 
I'll post the code as an edit to the original question in a minute.