# Changing Filter in Pivot Table connected to a OLAP Cube

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Pivot Table, that are connected to a OLAP cube. In this table i would like to change the value in the Report filter, depending a a cell value.
The report filter i like to change contains Administrators ID numbers which all starts with RS (fx RS34000).

I have tried to use this example, but that dosen't work, and it seems to be because my ID number is not a value.
[VBA to change Pivot Filter in OLAP cube to a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919139/vba-to-change-pivot-filter-in-olap-cube-to-a-range)

The only part I want to change in the code is the ID number "RSxxxxx".

Can someone please help me with this issue?

I have tried this but that dosn't work.

```
Dim MyArrayRS As Variant
Dim RS As Variant

Set RS = Range("RS_Nummer")

MyArrayRS = "Array(" & """[DimProjektRessource_ProjektAdministrator].[ProjektRessourceNr].&[RS" & RS & "]""" & ")"

Worksheets("KUBE").PivotTables("KUBE_NAV").PivotFields("[DimProjektRessource_ProjektAdministrator].[ProjektRessourceNr].[ProjektRessourceNr]").VisibleItemsList = MyArrayRS
```

This is the code when I record a macro that change the report filter.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("KUBE_NAV").PivotFields( _
    "[DimProjektRessource_ProjektAdministrator].[ProjektRessourceNr].[ProjektRessourceNr]" _
    ).VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[DimProjektRessource_ProjektAdministrator].[ProjektRessourceNr].&[RS34762]")
```

Comment: `"Array"` within quotes is not the same as `Array` - that seems problematic. `MyArrayRS` is a string but the recorded code shows the string inside `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`PivotField.VisibleItemsList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.visibleitemslist) documentation:

> Returns or sets a Variant specifying an **array** of strings that represent included items in a manual filter applied to a PivotField. Read/write

Currently you have `"Array"` as part of `MyArrayRS`: this is just the *String* "Array" and not the [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function) function.

Try the following:

```
Dim RS As Range
Set RS = Range("RS_Nummer")

Dim MyArrayRS As Variant
myArrayRS = Array("[DimProjektRessource_ProjektAdministrator].[ProjektRessourceNr].&[RS" & rs.Value & "]")
```